# LSB from array of bytes C#

Tags: c#, lsb

I need to select from an array of bytes an array of least significant bits into BitArray. I have code for searching  lsb. But I don't know how add this array to BitArray

```
private static bool GetBit(byte b)
        {
            return (b & 1) != 0;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add this array to BitArray"? It's unclear what you're asking here. It would really help if you'd give a complete example with expected output, with a "not sure what to do here" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first I would convert it to a bool array and then create the BitArray from this bool array :

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    BitArray bitArray = transform(byteArray);
}

private static bool GetBit(byte b)
{
    return (b & 1) != 0;
}

private static BitArray transform(byte[] byteArray)
{
    bool[] boolArray = new bool[byteArray.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
    {
        boolArray[i] = GetBit(byteArray[i]);
    }
    return new BitArray(boolArray);
}
```

**Edit:**
Here is the solution with an array of arrays :

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    byte[][] byteArrays = new byte[2][];
    byteArrays[0] = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    byteArrays[1] = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    BitArray[] bitArrays = new BitArray[byteArrays.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < byteArrays.Length; i++)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrays[i];
        bitArrays[i] = transform(byteArray);
    }
}

private static bool GetBit(byte b)
{
    return (b & 1) != 0;
}

private static BitArray transform(byte[] byteArray)
{
    bool[] boolArray = new bool[byteArray.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
    {
        boolArray[i] = GetBit(byteArray[i]);
    }
    return new BitArray(boolArray);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I am sorry, but if i have such array byte[][], what i need change in this code?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 5, 7, 8, 1, 3, 5, 6, 1, 0 };
>         byte[] b = bytes.Where(q => GetBit(q) == true).ToArray();
>         BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(b);            
>         Console.Read();
>     }
>
>     private static bool GetBit(byte b)
>     {
>         return (b & 1) != 0;
>     }
> ```

Comment: Please add some kind of explanation to your code. Your `Where` clause can also be simplified to `Where(GetBit)`.